# How to deploy appsmith via yaml in k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, appsmith

Any example appsmith yaml for deploying appsmith since I don't want use helm in prod environment?

Answer (score 1):

There's no official direct YAML files for deploying Appsmith on Kubernetes today. The Helm chart at helm.appsmith.com, and as documented at https://docs.appsmith.com/getting-started/setup/installation-guides/kubernetes, is the recommended way to install Appsmith on your cluster.

Asking as an engineering team member with Appsmith, can you elaborate a little on why avoid Helm for production please?

Comment: For service version tracing and follow our workflow as we all service are deployed via yaml.